# HTML Table Making

Tags: xhtml, html-table

For a sturdy guid I have to write an XHTML fragment that is a table of 3 rows. The first row has two elements 1 and 2. The second row has two elements 3 and 4. The final row has one element that spans both columns and contains the value 5. How would you do the last sentence(the final row)?

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
  <td>1, 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3,4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <span><td>5</td></span>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use the colspan parameter of td, similar to this W3schools example:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_colspan

Comment: your code ha only one column for 1,2 and 3,4 so your last row value cannot span to two columns

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
     <td>1, 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3,4</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td colspan="2">5</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

your code has only one column for 1,2 and 3,4 so your last row value cannot span to two columns. For that you have to modify it a bit

```
  <tr>
    <td>1 </td><td> 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td colspan="2">5</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish to use the colspan attribute. Assuming that you want 1 and 2 in the first row to be in 2 different columns (Your code doesn't do this), what you need is something like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td colspan = "2">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you do not understand this, please ask me again in the comments.